# How to get no of column which is spearated with pipe delimiter in python

Tags: python, formatting

I'm learning python, I'm trying to calculate the total no documents which is separated by pipe delimiter. For example:

```
test,abc,1232,,21,fd|lskd,vbd,3221,,983,ew|ploi,xsw,9073,,34,mn|opuye,few,45432,,234,df|
```

I'll be getting input live above - I've to calculate how many records there - each record is separated by pipe (|) delimiter.

So in this case total record is 4.

What's the efficient way of calculating in python, any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the input line in a variable named "a", the line you gave can be counted by:

```
len(a.split('|')) - 1
```

The "- 1" is required because of the extra '|' at the end of the line. If that does not occur with every line, a bit more checking is required. You could use a.endswith('|') to check for that situation.